# Gitlab-ci обновление secret сервисам docker swarm

Tags: gitlab-ci, docker-swarm

Хочу обновить secret в docker swarm используемый 2я сервисами из gitlab-ci.

Вывод команды `docker secret inspect secret` не содержит имен сервисов которые используют secret. Это можно узнать либо из сервисов, либо попытавшись удалить secret.

`- SERVICES=$(docker secret rm secret 2>&1 | grep -oE '[^ ]+\w$')`

Консольно все отрабатывает `echo $SERVICES` выводит ожидаемый результат 2х сервисов.
В gitlab-ci видимо не работает перенаправление stderr в stdout `2>&1` pipeline все равно ловит ошибку и падает с `ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1`

Как вы это решаете?